# How to use Conv1D as an input layer

Tags: keras

I am trying to use Conv1d as a first layer. I read the link https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/ but failed to understand.

If I use the first layer as dense like

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(12, input_dim=232, activation='relu'))
```

it works fine but if try to use the first layer as Conv1d like

```
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation = 'relu'))
```

I get an error as:

```
 Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 232)
```

My input size is 3000X232 and I am trying to learn whether a particular vector is present or not. So my output is either 0 or 1. If the vector is present in the input, the output is 1 and if the vector is absent in the input the output is 0. So I am learning a simple two-class classifier.

Can anyone help? Is it that there must be at least 2 spatial dimensions to use Conv1D?

Comment: Why do you call `Conv1D` twice?

Comment: @xdurch0, opps a typo, sorry.